# Java applet loading images not woking

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to create an applet that loads 52 cards, shuffles them(using random number generator), then displays the top 10 cards of the deck in two rows of five. Here is my code, but it doesn't seem to be printing any images.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;

public class cards extends Applet {
Image c1;
Image c2;
Image c3;
Image c4;
Image c5;
Image c6;
Image c7;
Image c8;
Image c9;
Image c10;
Image cj;
Image cq;
Image ck;
Image h1;
Image h2;
Image h3;
Image h4;
Image h5;
Image h6;
Image h7;
Image h8;
Image h9;
Image h10;
Image hj;
Image hq;
Image hk;
Image d1;
Image d2;
Image d3;
Image d4;
Image d5;
Image d6;
Image d7;
Image d8;
Image d9;
Image d10;
Image dj;
Image dq;
Image dk;
Image s1;
Image s2;
Image s3;
Image s4;
Image s5;
Image s6;
Image s7;
Image s8;
Image s9;
Image s10;
Image sj;
Image sq;
Image sk;
    public void init(){
    this.setBackground( Color.blue );
    c1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c1.gif" );
        c2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c2.gif" );
        c3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c3.gif" );
        c4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c4.gif" );
        c5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c5.gif" );
        c6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c6.gif" );
        c7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c7.gif" );
        c8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c8.gif" );
        c9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c9.gif" );
        c10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/c10.gif" );
        cj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/cj.gif" );
        cq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/cq.gif" );
        ck = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/ck.gif" );
        h1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h1.gif" );
        h2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h2.gif" );
        h3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h3.gif" );
        h4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h4.gif" );
        h5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h5.gif" );
        h6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h6.gif" );
        h7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h7.gif" );
        h8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h8.gif" );
        h9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h9.gif" );
        h10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/h10.gif" );
        hj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/hj.gif" );
        hq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/hq.gif" );
        hk = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/hk.gif" );
        d1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d1.gif" );
        d2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d2.gif" );
        d3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d3.gif" );
        d4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d4.gif" );
        d5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d5.gif" );
        d6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d6.gif" );
        d7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d7.gif" );
        d8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d8.gif" );
        d9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d9.gif" );
        d10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/d10.gif" );
        dj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/dj.gif" );
        dq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/dq.gif" );
        dk = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/dk.gif" );
        s1 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s1.gif" );
        s2 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s2.gif" );
        s3 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s3.gif" );
        s4 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s4.gif" );
        s5 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s5.gif" );
        s6 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s6.gif" );
        s7 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s7.gif" );
        s8 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s8.gif" );
        s9 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s9.gif" );
        s10 = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/s10.gif" );
        sj = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/sj.gif" );
        sq = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/sq.gif" );
        sk = getImage ( getDocumentBase (), "cards/sk.gif" );

    }
    public void paint( Graphics screen ){
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int x2 = 10;
    int y2 = 110;

        Image [] cards = new Image [ 52 ];
        cards [ 0 ] = c1;
        cards [ 1 ] = c2;
        cards [ 2 ] = c3;
        cards [ 3 ] = c4;
        cards [ 4 ] = c5;
        cards [ 5 ] = c6;
        cards [ 6 ] = c7;
        cards [ 7 ] = c8;
        cards [ 8 ] = c9;
        cards [ 9 ] = c10;
        cards [ 10 ] = cj;
        cards [ 11 ] = cq;
        cards [ 12 ] = ck;
        cards [ 13 ] = h1;
        cards [ 14 ] = h2;
        cards [ 15 ] = h3;
        cards [ 16 ] = h4;
        cards [ 17 ] = h5;
        cards [ 18 ] = h6;
        cards [ 19 ] = h7;
        cards [ 20 ] = h8;
        cards [ 21 ] = h9;
        cards [ 22 ] = h10;
        cards [ 23 ] = hj;
        cards [ 24 ] = hq;
        cards [ 25 ] = hk;
        cards [ 26 ] = d1;
        cards [ 27 ] = d2;
        cards [ 28 ] = d3;
        cards [ 29 ] = d4;
        cards [ 30 ] = d5;
        cards [ 31 ] = d6;
        cards [ 32 ] = d7;
        cards [ 33 ] = d8;
        cards [ 34 ] = d9;
        cards [ 35 ] = d10;
        cards [ 36 ] = dj;
        cards [ 37 ] = dq;
        cards [ 38 ] = dk;
        cards [ 39 ] = s1;
        cards [ 40 ] = s2;
        cards [ 41 ] = s3;
        cards [ 42 ] = s4;
        cards [ 43 ] = s5;
        cards [ 44 ] = s6;
        cards [ 45 ] = s7;
        cards [ 46 ] = s8;
        cards [ 47 ] = s9;
        cards [ 48 ] = s10;
        cards [ 49 ] = sj;
        cards [ 50 ] = sq;
        cards [ 51 ] = sk;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        screen.drawImage (cards[( int ) ( float ) Math.random () * 52 - 1], x, y, this);
        x = x + 5;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        screen.drawImage (cards [( int ) ( float ) ( Math.random () ) * 52 - ( int ) ( 1 )], x2, y2, this);
        x = x + 10;
    }
    }





}
```

Comment: Basic debugging (done by you) should be able to reveal which of these is true: "the images are not loaded correctly"; "the images are loaded correctly, but not displayed correctly"

Comment: Hey, I have a small idea: Can you try writing this code to display the top 1 card from a deck of cards that has a grand total of 1 card?

Comment: What have you done to solve the issue?

Comment: @JanDvorak How would I see if the images are loaded correctly?

Comment: I agree with @SaviourSelf. Try starting with something a little smaller. Can you write an applet which displays the image of a single card? If you run into trouble while trying to do this, please come back with more questions.

Comment: @CJSculti For starters, does anything show in the java console? If not, think of what can you print there to get the information? (Hint: if they're not loaded properly, the library should let you know)

Comment: @JanDvorak I am actually running the applet from an HTML page. I was not aware that you could run it from the command line?

Comment: @CJSculti you could run the applet in the IDE (netbeans support that) or you could add the console from the browser (not sure how)

Answer (score 2):

Even if the images are loaded, your applet dies on the first paint event, as the randomization always generates a card index of -1:

```
( int ) ( float ) Math.random () * 52 - 1
```

This is always -1 as the random number is generated between [0-1) and it is cast to integer, which rounds it down to zero. After that, you subtract one. It is an invalid index, and you get an exception.

Change this randomization code to a constant 0 to check if the loading is done properly.

If that is okay, you should really load the cards into an array on first time. That way you can shuffle them decently. Also, try to wrap the cards up to some class, for later on it will come handy.

Comment: Note: it is cast to an integer because the explicit cast occurs sooner than intended. The fix should be obvious.